# Add sequential row names into a table created using a for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I wrote the following program to create the table **combt**. I am trying to add rows names to this table but with no luck. I want to add a new column containing row names and each row to be named sequentially i.e. `(['Row' num2str(j)])`

```
%% Create tables.
combt = [];

%% Loop.
for i = [224:231, 271:281];
    j = sprintf('%04d', i)

%% Name the fit results sequentially.
comb.(['comb' j]) = cfit(fitresult);

%% Export combined variables to table.
combt = [combt;comb.(['comb' j])];

end

%% Name the columns.
final = dataset({combt 'a','b','c','d','wa','wb','wc','wd','xa','xb','xc','xd','y0','rsquare'});
```

The current table looks like this:

[image: The current table looks like this]

I need it to look like this (The row names can be achieved by `(['Row' num2str(j)])`):

[image: I need it to look like this]

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you want. Do you want to create a struct "combt" with fields (['comb' j]) ? or do you want to create a dataset which each entry is named differently?

Comment: Or do you have lets say a `20x300` Matrix which you want to change to `21x300` where the old entrys are sent one place back and the new first row includes the row names which you want to have numerated?

Comment: I updated the post by adding pictures explaining what I want my results to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help. I found a very simple answer, which will add the sequential file numbers in separate column ( all I had to do was add  `row.(['row' j]) = [i , comb.(['comb' j])]` and offcourse another column name `'row'` in `final = dataset({combt 'row', 'a','b','c','d','wa','wb','wc','wd','xa','xb','xc','xd','y0','rsquare'});`).

Giving:

```
%% Create tables.
combt = [];

%% Loop.
for i = [224:231, 271:281];
    j = sprintf('%04d', i)

%% Name the fit results sequentially.
comb.(['comb' j]) = cfit(fitresult);

%% Add a column.
row.(['row' j]) = [i , comb.(['comb' j])]


%% Export combined variables to table.
combt = [combt;row.(['row' j])];

end

%% Name the columns.
final = dataset({combt 'row', 'a','b','c','d','wa','wb','wc','wd','xa','xb','xc','xd','y0','rsquare'});
```

Yielding the following table:

[image]

Comment: This works only if you want to have numbers in that row. In your above given picture for the wanted result you said: 'Row227'. If you want that check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to initialize the combt variable with the different names just do this.

```
%% Loop.
for i = [224:231, 271:281];
    j = sprintf('%04d', i)

    %% Export combined variables to table.
    combt.(['comb' j])]=[];

end
```

if you want to give names to entries do this:

```
aaa=1:10;
for i=1:length(aaa)
    names{i}=['c',num2str(i)];
end
aaa_dataset = dataset(aaa','ObsNames',names)
```

in your case (make sure you have a name for each entry):

```
final = dataset(combt,'ObsNames',{'a','b','c','d','wa','wb','wc','wd','xa','xb','xc','xd','y0','rsquare'});
```

if you want the names to be added to the matrix:

```
a=rand(10,10);
for i=1:10
    names{i}=['c',num2str(i)];
end

a_cell=cell(size(a,1),size(a,2)+1);
a_cell(1:end,2:end)=num2cell(a);
a_cell(1:end,1)=names
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save different data formats into one matrix you should use cell. In your case create a new data_array (where you want to save it):

```
my_old_size = size(my_old_data);
my_new_data= cell(my_old_size(1),my_old_size(2)+1);
```

Then you transform each element to str, cell or char. since you can't write double into cell and write it to the new place.

```
for k=1:my_old_size(1)
  for l=1:my_old_size(2)
    my_new_data(k,l+1)= {my_old_data(k,l)};
  end
end
```

Last but not least you add your Row names. Pay attention that you should define the constant part of your Row-name outside the loop, otherwise strcat will add each value to the existing name:

```
my_rowname = 'Row_';
for k=1:my_old_size(1)
  my_new_matrix(k,1) = strcat(my_rowname,num2str(k));
end
```

This results in Row_1, Row_2,...., Row_(my_old_size) 
If you want you can use `char(my_old_data(k,l)` to convert your data to char instead of string as given above. Same goes for your rownames. instead of `num2str` you can use `char()` again. 
 
I split the definition of row-names and writing the data so that it is easier to understand but for time relevance i would implement the code so you only loop once over the data. Also if you want to address your data again you can just use

```
my_new_matrix{m,n}
```

to get the argument inside that cell.